# Unable to Map Data to Child Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Basically I'm doing it wothout Arrow function to map all the data to Card Component but
Im unable to map data to child component, but console log & manually is showing the data but not when I'm mapping.

I want to do thing without Arrow function

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

App Component render at index.js

```
import React from "react";
import CardComp from "./card.js";
import sdata from "./sdata";

sdata.map(App);

function App(val){
    // console.log(data)

    return(
        <>
        {console.log(val.first_name)}
        <CardComp src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" 
        title={val.id}
        text={val.email}
        bttext={val.gender}
        />
        </>
    )
}

export default App;
```

Card Component

```
import React from 'react'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';


function CardComp(props) {
  return (
    <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
      <Card.Img variant="top" src={props.src} />
      <Card.Body>
        <Card.Title>{props.title}</Card.Title>
        <Card.Text>
          {props.text}
        </Card.Text>
        <Button variant="primary">{props.bttext}</Button>
      </Card.Body>
    </Card>
  )
}

export default CardComp;
```

raw Jason Data Array

```
const data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "first_name": "Andriana",
    "last_name": "Goodale",
    "email": "agoodale0@nsw.gov.au",
    "gender": "Female",
    "ip_address": "82.200.197.74"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "first_name": "Coralie",
    "last_name": "Aisman",
    "email": "caisman1@mtv.com",
    "gender": "Female",
    "ip_address": "214.55.245.199"
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "first_name": "Allan",
    "last_name": "Armatage",
    "email": "aarmatage2@army.mil",
    "gender": "Male",
    "ip_address": "181.180.166.43"
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the mapping of data inside the component without using arrow function as:

```
function App(val) {
  return (
    <>
      {sdata.map(function (val) {
        return (
          <CardComp
            src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"
            title={val.id}
            text={val.email}
            bttext={val.gender}
          />
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sdata.map(App.bind(this);
```

or

```
sdata.map(App.bind(React);
```

Answer (score 0):

try to modify the App component, and map the data to cardComp components:

```
function App(val){
    return(
        <>
         {
            val.map(e=>
                <CardComp src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"
                    title={e.id}
                    text={e.email}
                    bttext={e.gender}
                />
                )
            }
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

---

You are exporting App, but App return just some code and not actually the result of map.
Inside App you need to return the result of Map(an array of Cards). Here you can see a real example [stackblitz working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-ft9tq8?file=App.js)
Here you can see [map works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
function App() {
  // console.log(data)
  function GetCard(val) {
    return (
      <>
        {console.log(val.first_name)}
        <CardComp
          src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"
          title={val.id}
          text={val.email}
          bttext={val.gender}
        />
      </>
    );
  }

  return <>{data.map(GetCard)}</>;
}

export default App;
```